# C# InternetExplorer and Thread Throwing "System.NotSupportedException"

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, internet-explorer

I am sure I had my SIP (solution in progress) working as it was supposed to, now it's not - perhaps a recent update to WebViewer has thrown a spanner in the works - (a bad workman blames his tools, a really bad one blames someone else and their tools)

Basically part of the SIP is to set up 2 threads that independently refresh internet pages and read the data. I could tell this was working because there is a little icon that pops up when the page is refreshing and this was happening every 500 milliseconds as programmed.

So far so good, but things have stopped working. Now I can have either page 1 refreshing or page 2, but not both - the other one throws an exception 'System.NotSupportedException' with exactly the same code as the other.

I have spent a good while rewriting, even combining the 2 threads into 1 which refreshes and reads both in a for loop. But no success.

And so I present some example code which I have written to reproduce the situation, hopefully there are many gurus out there who can spot at a glance what the solution to the solution is.

```
    public class PageChecker
    {
        internal InternetExplorer[] CheckPages = { null, null };
        internal Thread ThreadChecker;
        internal PageChecker()
        {
            CheckPages[0] = new InternetExplorer();
            CheckPages[0].Visible = true;
            CheckPages[0].Navigate2("https://google.com");
            CheckPages[1] = new InternetExplorer();
            CheckPages[1].Visible = true;
            CheckPages[1].Navigate2("https://yahoo.com");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ThreadChecker = new Thread(PageCheck);
            ThreadChecker.Start();
        }
        internal void PageCheck()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                for (int pgn = 0; pgn < 2; pgn++)
                {
                    int i = CheckPages[pgn].Document.GetElementsByTagName("td").Length;
                    // line above throws exception "System.NotSupportedException" when pgn = 1
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found out that there is an infinite loop( `while(true)` ) in the code you provided, so the problem I am getting is `OutOfMemoryException`, not `NotSupportedException` what you mentioned. I think you need to check it.

Comment: Many thanks for taking a look; I re-ran the example and you are right, Studio reports "Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.", however, the program does not exit, but carries on - reporting the "System.NotSupportedException" error on each loop. Rather strange. Not sure why the insufficient memory error occurs, nor why the program continues. Perhaps the 1st error makes the 2nd occur. But why does the 1st error occur? it is wrapped as a Windows Form solution - perhaps this is also a factor ?

Comment: I just tested it in a Console project. You can also modify your code appropriately (remove the infinite loop) and try again to check if it has the same issue.